# How to programmatically set the position of a button in ios with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
startButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, startButton.frame.width, startButton.frame.height)
```

in `viewDidLoad`. However this seems to make no difference.

What are the correct way of doing such thing?

Comment: you are using autolayout?

Comment: You are not adding any difference though.. Whats not working?

Comment: The code seems all right. Did you check that startButton.frame.width and startButton.frame.height have the values you expect and not 0.0, when hitting the line in your question ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to change position if not usign AutoLayout,

```
var X_Position:CGFloat? = 50.0 //use your X position here
var Y_Position:CGFloat? = 50.0 //use your Y position here

startButton.frame = CGRectMake(X_Position, Y_Position, startButton.frame.width, startButton.frame.height)
```

Comment: Can I use this together with AutoLayout?

Comment: No, If you are working with autolayout then frame change won't work, you must update your position constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best way to set the position of your button is to use constraints! Here are some of mine that I used :)

```swift
     let storeBtnImg = UIImage(named: "StoreButton")
        storeBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        storeBtn.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 7.8, self.frame.height / 1.9), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 10, height: self.frame.height / 10))
        storeBtn.backgroundColor = nil
        storeBtn.addTarget(self, action: "storeBtnAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        storeBtn.setImage(storeBtnImg, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.view?.addSubview(storeBtn)

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: storeBtn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: storeBtn, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -75).active = true
```

The important parts are always remember to set `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

and to put `.active = true` at the end of your constraint.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer doing all UI programmatically. An example would be:

```
// Button declaration
private lazy var upVoteButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(anObjcActionSelector), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()


// Method that configures your views
private func configureLayout() {
    addSubview(upVoteButton)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            upVoteButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            upVoteButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            upVoteButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAncher, constant: 32)
            // You can trust some attributes, like the width, to autolayout if you want
        ])

}
```

You can take a look at the `constraint` method [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutdimension), it's quite complete.

You can also use [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit). If you're doing a big app completely programmatic it can save you from some boring cumbersome code.